# How can I modify a Woocommerce shipping label

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a Wordpress Woocommerce site. I need to have the International Flat Rate Shipping say "Call Us For Rates" instead of "International Shipping (Free)". The only value that I can change on the admin side that updates this text is to add a price. There is no way to add a label or change the price or free to text.

Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [**`woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label`**](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label/) filter for this.

Add the following code to your theme **functions.php** (preferably a child-theme)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'change_shipping_label', 10, 2 );

function change_shipping_label( $full_label, $method ){

    $full_label = str_replace( "International Shipping (Free)", "Call Us For Rates", $full_label );

    return $full_label;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You are amazing!!