# How to change Woocommerce shipping labels in cart, checkout and also on orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, shipping-method

I'm trying to change the shipping label based on whether any of the products in cart has an addon.

For that purpose, I am using *[How can I modify a Woocommerce shipping label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511363/how-can-i-modify-a-woocommerce-shipping-label/37511729#37511729)* answer code, with some changes to suit my needs.

The HTML:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate5" value="flat_rate:5" class="shipping_method">
<label class="shipping__list_label" for="shipping_method_0_flat_rate5">Standard Shipping (2-3 days): <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>3,95<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span></label>
```

So the label *Standard Shipping (2-3 days)* must display *Shipping with customization (4-6 days)* if a certain condition is met (in this case: the field *custom_text* is not empty).

The functions.php:

```php
//Change Standard Shipping Label if product is customized
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_shipping_method_full_label', 'change_shipping_label', 10, 2 );
function change_shipping_label( $full_label, $method ){
    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( !empty( $cart_item['custom_text'] ) ) {
        $full_label = str_replace( "Standard Shipping (2-3 days)", "Shipping with customization (4-6 days)", $full_label );
        }
    }   
    return $full_label;
}
```

This was a success. If the condition is met the label changes to Shipping with customization (4-6 days) prior checkout.

However, the label change does not apply after checkout (thank you page and emails, it displays the original "Standard Shipping (2-3 days)".

Can I display this label change also on thank you page and emails?

Comment: That is the thing, it should also affect the original display also in orders and emails. The shipping method is a flat rate which label displays the estimated delivery time (2-4 days). What I want to achieve is to change it for (4-6 days) if a condition is true, which this code does well, except for "orders and emails" as you say...

Not sure what shipping method rate Id acually means, but I hope it is found here:

<input type="hidden" name="shipping_method[0]" data-index="0" id="shipping_method_0_flat_rate5" value="flat_rate:5" class="shipping_method">

Comment: Nothing is adding estimated delivery time, it is just the name of the label for the only shipping method available: I called it  "Standard Shipping (2-3 days)". I've updated the question. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: The shipping method is a flat rate called  "Standard Shipping (2-3 days)". Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. I can change the string with "Shipping with customization (4-6 days)" by using the function above. The change displays in the checkout page, but in the order it displays the original string: "Standard Shipping (2-3 days)".

Comment: I have answered… I hope it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2**

Based on the provided code and informations, to change specific shipping label on orders, using shipping rate Id to target the desired shipping method:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_shipping_item', 'action_wc_checkout_create_order_shipping_item', 10, 4 );
function action_wc_checkout_create_order_shipping_item( $item, $package_key, $package, $order ) {
    // Targeting "flat_rate:5" by its instance ID
    if( $item->get_instance_id() == 5 ) {
        $item->set_method_title( "Shipping with customization (4-6 days)" );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**Related:** [Change specific shipping method title on WooCommerce orders after checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65754067/change-specific-shipping-method-title-on-woocommerce-orders-after-checkout/65754102#65754102)

Comment: I'm testing and for now it doesn't seem to work... I'll try also with the related question and I will post here if it sorts it out.